Core-level spectroscopies in correlated mixed-valence compounds
I have recently attempted to simulate core-level spectra (XAS, RIXS, EELS) in correlated mixed-valence compounds, but I am at a loss of what method might describe these systems best.
My go-to method so far was exact diagonalization of cluster Hamiltonians as these spectroscopies are mostly local probes into the electronic structure. For simple structures and compounds, this works very well. However, for more complex mixed-valence compounds, assembly of larger clusters is necessary for capturing metal-metal charge fluctuations which gets computationally expensive very fast.
I have attempted DFT-based techniques such as TDDFT or solving the BSE in these materials, but the single-particle picture often does not reproduce the correct electronic structure to begin with (e.g. metallic behavior where the material is a correlated insulator in reality) and my results so far are lacking.
As a remedy, I have started looking into DFT+DMFT methods, but extracting XAS/RIXS spectra seems more complicated and I could find no code streamlining such a workflow from projecting DFT results onto a suitable basis, building and solving the impurity model, … Also, conceptually, I am uncertain about how multiple metal sites should be implemented to get correct results.
Thus, my question is:

What other methods am I missing that might help for these type of simulations?
Does DFT+DMFT capture the mixed-valence nature of these materials on a conceptual level and if yes, what code could be a more pedagogical entry into these kind of simulations?


You can use the ORCA program for this kind of calculations. The general workflow is

Build a cluster model, where you designate a few tens of atoms (including a few metal atoms) to be described at a high level of theory, which is surrounded by about one hundred atoms described by embedding potential, and finally a few tens of thousands of point charges.
Launch the actual calculation, where you can use the DFT/ROCIS method for calculating the core excitation spectra, under the embedding field of all the surrounding atoms. As DFT/ROCIS is more accurate than TDDFT (in particular it does not suffer from spin contamination) but much less expensive than exact diagonalization, you can afford to treat many metal sites at once with DFT/ROCIS.
If you can afford it, you can also use multireference methods NEVPT2, DCD-CAS(2) etc. in place of DFT/ROCIS. These methods perform an exact diagonalization within a small active space, say <20 orbitals, and treat remaining electron correlation perturbatively.

For a detailed introduction of DFT/ROCIS, see the respective section in the ORCA manual. For an introduction of the embedding potential approach in ORCA, see this section.

Thank you for your suggestion - I will certainly look into this. Coming more from a solid-state physics background, I now realize I have a bit of catching up to do on the more chemistry-inspired approaches
